# Selecting a SelectOneMenu populated with enum only after second click

Tags: primefaces, enums, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use enums to populate a PrimeFaces selectOneMenu, but could not get the selected value. **After the first click**, the value assigned is always the one in the post-constructor.

HTML:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="periodo"
                 value="#{dashboardMB.enumDate}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardMB.enumDates}"
                 var="enumDate" 
                 itemValue="#{enumDate}"
                 itemLabel="#{enumDate.label}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Backing bean:

```
private EnumDate enumDate;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    enumDate = EnumDate.YEAR;
}
```

EnumDate:

```
public enum EnumData {
    EMPTY("- Select -"), DAY("Day"), WEEK("Week"), FORTNIGHT("Fortnight"), MONTH("Month"), BIMESTER("Bimester"), TRIMESTER("Trimester"), SEMESTER("Semester"), YEAR("Year");
    public String label;
    public static final EnumSet<EnumDate> all = EnumSet.of(EMPTY, DAY, WEEK, FORTNIGHT, MONTH, BIMESTER, TRIMESTER, SEMESTER, YEAR);

    private EnumDate(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Thus, it has always the value "Year". Until the button which sends the form is clicked again.

Solved using OmniFaces converter:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="period"
                 converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                 style="width: 237px !important"
                 value="#{dashboardMB.enumDate}"
                 filter="true"
                 filterMatchMode="contains"
                 panelStyleClass="oneMenuPanel"
                 styleClass="oneMenu">
  <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardMB.enumDateArray}"
                 var="enum"
                 itemValue="#{enum}"
                 itemLabel="#{enum.label}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The `enumDateArray` attribute is of `EnumDate[]` type. Its getter returns `EnumDate.values()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use the [omnifaces generic enum converter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter). It keeps your code cleaner compared to 'manually' doing conversions of lists etc...

Comment: I'll follow this approach. Actually I had to use the `SelectItemsConverter`, because it's not a multi selection menu. But, still, it's getting "Year" value. And I get NPE if I don't initialize the enumDate attribute with some default value.

Comment: Made these changes. Then, I found out it gets the value only after I send the form again. I was using `p:ajax` in `p:commandButton`. Get rid of it and used the own button's `update` and `action` attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Convert enums into Strings

`EnumData[] eds = EnumData.values();
 String EDtoString = eds[0].name();`

You can pass function `String[] EnumDatasToString()` to XHTML.

To convert from String to Enum use

`EnumData ed = EnumData.valueOf(EDToString);`